# What are the conditions on the points that make up a tetrahedron?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

So I have the following question to solve.

For which $a\in\mathbb{R}$ are the points $P = (−1, 2, 1)$, $Q = (−11, 0, 1)$, $R = (a, −1, 4)$ and
$S = (0, 1, a)$ vertices in a tetrahedron? Determine the area of the triangle $P QR$
and the volume of the tetrahedron $PQRS$ for such values of $a$. (Positively oriented
ON-system assumed.)

The question above seems weird since I thought that four points make up a tetrahedron if and only if the points are not coplanar. So for the question above I just need to find the values $a$ for which the four points are coplanar and for every other value of $a$ we have a tetrahedron. But this gives infinite values $a$ so I'm thinking maybe my assumption about the necessary and sufficient condition for four points to make up a tetrahedron is wrong.

Comment: Take an equilateral triangle  then draw a line perpendicular to it through its center. Any point outside the plane and on that line will form a tetrahedron. So even when we constrain ourselves to a specific type of tetrahedron you have a lot of freedom for how you choose the fourth point.

Answer (score 2):

$\vec{PQ}=<-11-(-1),0-2,1-1>=<-10,-2,0>$

$\vec{PR}=<a-(-1),-1-2,4-1>=<a+1,-3,3>$

$\vec{PS}=<0-(-1),1-2,a-1>=<1,-1,a-1>$

They must make a volume, so $\left|\begin{matrix} -10&-2&0\\a+1&-3&3\\1&-1&a-1\end{matrix}\right|\neq 0\implies a\neq -17$ and $a\neq 2$.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy: \langle and \rangle

Comment: So many latex rules instead of a pen.